# rich:calendar positioning in css

Tags: css, calendar, richfaces, jsf-2.2

Lets take a look on below images as example

[image]

As you see that in first case calendar cuts-off from the bottom. I've used `<rich:calendar> ... </rich:calendar>`

In first case my `panel`'s `height: 945px;` (not enough `height` to adjust the calendar) but for second `height: 1000px;`. This is also come when I have not enough panel's `width` (like in **mobile**).

I am not free to change panel's `height: 945px;`.

panel is simple `div` having some height and width.

*P.S:* I tried `z-index: 10;` but it doesn't help me. I cannot provide JSFIddle because it doesnot support `richfaces:calendar`. What can I do for this?

I am using JSF 2.2 and richfaces 4.x.

Comment: Please add a [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net) or something, it would be more helpful.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay JSFiddle don't support `<rich:calendar>` so it is difficult to reproduce it via JSFiddle.

Comment: without your actual conditions its difficult to give a solution.

Comment: But you can provide actual panel (which panel? rich:panel, h:panelGrid or h:panelGroup or  even something else - we don't know that) and rich:calendar code from *.xhtml file. We don't know what you are exactly setting there.

Also always write about your JSF and RF version.

Comment: @Emkas panel is simple `div` having some height and width.

Comment: Are you really sure that you're using RF 2 (TWO)? As far as I know, versions < 4.5 doesn't support JSF 2.2. Please be more specific, paste your actual code (cut if from any not needed stuff), then maybe someone will try to help you.

Comment: aaaaaaaand? Did you find the solution?

Comment: @EmilSierżęga I am not able to find good solution.

Answer (score 0):

`rich:calendar` is simple `<table>` inside `<div>`, there's no magic there.

Since you don't want to provide us code (even on multiple requests; and nobody here wants to guess), I'd try with increasing z-index in tag:

```
<rich:calendar zindex="4"/>
```

then with CSS

```
table.rf-cal-popup { z-index: 4; }
```

Four is what you need (default value is 3), but I don't know generated HTML, so you can increase it to some big number, like 1001. There must be something wrong with z-index, because `rich:calendar` always generates full calendar (full table with calendar).